# Is there a way to use a TFS2010 but that gets the code from a TFS2008?

Tags: tfs, build

at our company we are using a TFS 2008 server. We need some capabilities offered by TFS 2010 (like Lab Management) but currently we cannot change the server (we're a small part of a big company and doing that would make others to update their tools so it's not an option).

What I'm looking for is a way to install a TFS 2010 server that links somehow to the repository of the actual TFS server so when the 2010 MSBuild tries to build he takes sources from TFS2008.

Is this possible or do you think that could be another way of getting that to work?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Thanks, a not can be a valid answer too. Someone knows if is this 100% accurate?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Integration platform to sync the sources and work items of TFS2008 with TFS2010.
See http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/ for more information

Comment: Really interesting and definitively worth a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also customize a build template so that it pulls in source code from anywhere.